# PostgreSQL: Error using pg_read_binary_file: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Postgres 9.1 Version:

Trying to update using below script:

```
update  tbl_application_biometrics set  
on_site_picture = pg_read_binary_file 
('C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\data\upda\Doc\pic\ON-A-R102516-03288.jpg')    
where id =  1;
```

Error Shows:

[Err] ERROR:  could not stat file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/data/upda/Doc/pic/ON-A-R102516-03288.jpg": No such file or directory

What i missing?

Last time i successfully update this using same command.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe file permissions? Postgres often runs under the user account "network service" which has little rights.

Comment: Already set it full rights

Comment: login as postgres and try oppening it?.. or check windows logs for OS exlanation on the error